# Объединение двух таблиц SQL(Delphi)

Tags: sql, delphi, ado

Я считываю данные с двух БД формата dbf посредством 2-х ADOQuery, DATASource и ADOConnection в разные DBGrid.

Первая таблица имеет поля - NC, DOT, GOR, QN, QBT, DDRMNC, QGAN.

Вторая таблица - NC, DOT, GOR, QBM, DRS.

Необходимо объединить две таблицы так, чтобы поля следовали в определенном порядке:

```
NC     DOT(дата)    GOR    QN    QBT    QBM     QGAN    DRMNC=DRS(объеденить в одном поле)
```

Сортируя по NC и DOT в сторону увеличения. До этого никогда не имел дело с БД, поэтому испытываю большие трудности.

Comment: можно загрузить данные в промежуточный ClientDataSet, MemData и дальше проводить манипуляции с данными в памяти.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Первая таблица 
INNER JOIN Вторая таблица on Вторая таблица.DOT = Первая таблица.DOT 
ORDER BY Первая таблица.NC
```

Примерно так..

Comment: Обратите внимание - "Я считываю данные **с двух БД** формата dbf посредством **2-х** ADOQuery"

Comment: А если у меня обе базы загружаются через OpenDialog и изменение данных должны происходить в программе для дальнейшей выгрузки  в файл, а исходные базы не должны меняться?

Comment: @dega тогда можно загрузить данные в промежуточный ClientDataSet, MemData... и работать с набором в памяти. Если конечно базы небольшие.

Comment: А если базы могут быть большие и маленькие? Пользователь сам будет выбирать какие...